# Random areas of random SE sites produce 500 errors at random times. Randomly

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am getting a 500 server error when I try to load the main page and the Questions tab. Jobs, Documentation, user profiles, etc seem to work fine, but I cannot access questions. This has been the case for around 15 minutes so far.

When accessing the Questions tab the site works sometimes, but most of the times is down.

(In case it's relevant to CDN, error appears in Spain, India)

[image]

It's only happening when logged in:

[image]

Comment: It's happening for me on the profile page also. On any SE site I try. For me it's been around 15 mins.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't happen for me. Could be a CDN issue; where in the world are you located?

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296438/unexpected-error-occurred-while-you-were-browsing-our-site-profile-page

Comment: @MartinSmith I still see the issue. It has been working fine before, but it seems to be down for about 15 minutes. Only front page and questions seem to be affected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm located in Spain

Comment: Happens for me in Australia. Only when I'm signed in though.

Comment: Not working for me too (Poland). Have problem with Software Engineering and Code Review, too.

Comment: This is only happening if you are signed in

Comment: Works for me, in Spain

Comment: So not necessarily related to location, but with your profile, because multiple locations report the issue, some people in the same geographic locations don't see it, and people don't see it when logged out.

Comment: Yes, as @BenitoBertoli said, only happening if you are logged in

Comment: Same.. and enjoying some _cool pics_ from every _refresh_! Some one convey when it will be back! Site appears normal for users who are not logged in

Comment: Updated the post: the Questions tab seems to be working _sometimes_: most of the time is down but sometimes it loads fine.

Comment: This is very random. Stack Overflow main page is fine for me. My profile page isn't. Parenting main page isn't whilst Workplace is. Workplace Meta isn't though. Very hit and miss. Do you have issues on other SE sites? I've reported it on MSE. Pang has linked above.

Comment: Happened me when i signed into the Super User account. Error displayed only in the profile page

Comment: Questions not listed in SO, Profile not listed in Unix & Linux, Super User, Database Administrator

Comment: In Italy too, questions page works, profile down.

Comment: Happening for me on U&L and SO.  Checked Super User and it worked (I wasn't logged in), then I logged in and it showed the right page.  Checked back at U&L and it was working and I was logged out.  Logged in and it stopped working.  Went to SU and it had stopped working.

Comment: Same here in Sri-Lanka as well

Comment: @MartijnPieters Happening for me too in India... Those pics are funny.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not sure if this is: Can not land directly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php, but can land at https://stackoverflow.com/questions and then switch to my favorite tab - PHP and it works!!!

Comment: Its working now!!! and again its gone. Whats happening

Comment: @MartijnPieters I like the new title, looks more accurate

Comment: It's not working on Spain either

Comment: Same in Austria. If I use private browsing it works.

Comment: I guess is something with the redirection from StackOverflow.com to serve the data on /questions

Comment: Cannot see the question tab when logged in, from Germany. Can browse the questions when not logged in, e.g. in a newly opened private window. I can view specific question, e.g. via the notifications, but i cannot see the questions overview.

Comment: Can not see the User Profile Tab, from Taiwan.

Comment: I think [this Jamaican](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/263319349.jpg) is playing some melodies while [SO developer](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/263319349.jpg) is fixing this problem. Next time SO can introduce some GIF of such funny moments :)

Comment: Happening for me as well when I try to load my Profile

Comment: Is that a unicorn?

Comment: I've the same problem:)

Comment: It seems that here (Italy) has started to work again.

Comment: @Steve Looks like it's back for everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well that was fun to wake up to, sorry!

We should be back online for all users now - this was a single web server in the web tier hitting out of memory errors and being unable to even log as a result. It wasn't showing for everyone because it was:

- 1 server of 9 total serving [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)
- Largely didn't impact anonymous users (only 30 of 8,372 affected requests) because most of the page is cached and doesn't allocate much. Logged-in users get a more personalized homepage and we do a lot more work (allocating more memory).

The feed that calculates things for the mobile app went off the rails at 30GB and was impacting the other app pools. I'll be digging into that today.

Comment: Turn it off an on again, pretend nothing happened and walk away whistling right? That's what most people do! :P

Comment: @DavidG If it was only up to me, I'd kill the mobile feed completely and a lot of headaches would go away :( Users are using it though - so we've gotta figure something out. It's not designed for the scale it's now running at...and it's really starting to show. Needs love ASAP.

Comment: Should be easy enough to fix, just like adding SSL was right?

Comment: Hah, so that's why my mobile feed came back to life (after days of no updates)!