# Homepage 500 Error

Tags: bug, homepage

I'm sure the staff already know, but I'm getting the **Oops! Something Bad Happened! (Working on ur problemz)** page when attempting to visit the homepage of SO.

Refreshed, cleared cookies, etc. Still happening.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349741/random-areas-of-random-se-sites-produce-500-errors-at-random-times-randomly

Comment: yeah, we're investigating; something is very odd